# Show all entries where relationship exists (eloquent)

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Trying to build an eloquent query to return all results in the database where a relationship exists.

```
$deliveries = Deliverer::has('deliveries')->get()->toArray();

dd($deliverer);
```

This is returning results which include multiple deliverers without any deliveries.

Deliverer Model includes:

```
public function deliveries() {
  return $this->hasMany(Deliveries::class)->latest();
}
```

Delivery Model includes:

```
public function deliverer() {
  return $this->belongsTo(Deliverer::class);
}
```

Can anybody see what is going wrong here please?

Comment: Do you mean `Deliverer::has('deliveries')` instead of `Delivery::has('deliveries')`?

Comment: Sorry a typo! Will edit.

Comment: What's the result of `dd(Deliverer::has('deliveries')->toSql());`?

Comment: `"select * from 'deliverers' where exists (select *, (select count(*) from 'bid_for_deliveries' where 'deliveries'.'id' = 'bid_for_deliveries'.'delivery_id' and 'bid_for_deliveries'.'deleted_at' is null) as 'bids_count' from 'deliveries' where 'deliverers'.'id' = 'deliveries'.'deliverer_id' and 'deliveries'.'deleted_at' is null) and 'deliverers'.'deleted_at' is null"`

Comment: The query looks good. What database are you using? Provide some sample data on http://sqlfiddle.com that lets us reproduce the problem.